# How to find RGB values from texel contained in an area?

Tags: python, texturing

With the Blender Python API, I am trying to get the RBG Values of all the texels from the ground object(the color checker in the following example), that are contained in the orthogonal projection of the active object(the black rectangle):

[image]

In this example, this would return: (Blue(4),green(3),yellow(2),red(1),orange(8), grey(7),pink(6)). If there is no solution for the complete area, I would at least like to get the values for each vertex (here : green(3) and pink(6)).

The point is to have my my object to be build parametrically depending on the datas in the ground texture where it stands.

How can I achieve this with Blender?

Comment: It's still a little difficult to tell what you're trying to do. Could you elaborate some more?

Comment: Sounds like you want a set of unique RGB values, what is it good for? Is this somehow about texture interpolation?

Comment: THe goal is too get the value inside the black rectangle. The color raster is the second object in the selection, the rectangle the active object. It's an orthogonal top view. Goal is too build a parametric object from the rectangle, depending on what value are on the ground(the color raster)

Comment: Another way to see it : depending on the position of the building ( black rectangle in the image), it will be build differently. Like if it is above a texel (R1G1B1) it will be extruded of 10 meters, if it's above a texel (R2B2G2) it will be extruded of 20m. But for that, I have to get the values of the underlying texels on the ground.